# HTML anchor #bottom, only going half-way down page

Tags: html

http://www.planet-tolkien.com/board/44/621/0/poll-suggestions

It's due to the multiple "bottom of the page" anchor links on each post to the anchor name at the bottom of the page. I tried to solve this by using a unique id and name for the attributes:

```
<a href="#bottom" id="4656" name="4656">
```

But this hasn't worked.

Suggestions?

P.S. Don't use the URL bar, yes that works. Visit the page and click on a link in a post that says "Bottom of the page". This is where it isn't working.

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the problem?

Comment: Another "works great" here too (on Ffx _and_ Chrome). I think we've got that covered. You shouldn't need to add a unique id to the ` <a> ` tag for this to work. That's just creating more work for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pound sign (#) denotes a css id and ids are only supposed to be used once.  Although, when I entered it as part of the url, i.e. http://www.planet-tolkien.com/board/44/621/0/poll-suggestions**#bottom** it did bring me to the bottom of the page.  I tested this in safari and firefox and worked fine.

Comment: It's not working in Chrome, and members are reporting it's not working.

Comment: It works for me when entering it as part of the URL too, just not when clicking on the links on the page. Hmmmm.

Comment: Try clicking on a link in a post that says "Bottom of the page" rather than using the URL bar, that's when it doesn't work.

Comment: I was. :) No problems. This is certainly bizarre.

Comment: both (using a direct link / klicking the buttons) works for me in FF 3.6.13

Comment: @Anthony In this case the pound sign is denoting a Page Anchor, not a Css id.  _Completely_ different usages!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move the  into the footer DIV, rather than outside it. I can't claim credit for this though, my friend Anton figured it out :)